How do I render a view with partials when Rails only wants to call render once?
In a controller action, I want to respond to a POST request with some JSON. Some of the JSON is rendered HTML. There are other important fields in the JSON, so I am rendering the template manually like this:
html = File.open('app/views/shared/_my_partial.html.erb').read
template = ERB.new(html)

html = template.result(binding)

render json: {status: 'OK', html: html, other_important_stuff: foo}

However, this means that I can't use any partials in the _my_partial.html.erb, like this:
<%= render partial: 'shared/my_inner_partial', locals: {var: var}

...because this provokes the error "(Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action".
What is the right approach here? I'd like to render a partial with the ability to render other nested partials inside. However I would like to send this to the client as part of a JSON response, with other fields in it which I need to set in the controller action.

"What is the right approach here?" - I would say that approach taken by Turbo where it uses  custom mime types to deliver chunks of HTML as plain old text is much better than dealing with the headaches of escaping HTML and shoving it into JSON and then unescaping it on the other end without creating XSS vulnerabilies.

Thanks - yes I could rip out this whole approach and try something better. I don't want to use Turbo, however. The actual requirement is to send some HTML, and some JSON variables, to the client in the same request. Is there a better approach?
Maybe I could embed the JSON in the HTML rather than the other way round.
Any documentation on the Turbo approach?

DoubleRenderError happens when you call controller render method multiple times, which is different from a view render helper. But because you're using ERB directly and binding to a controller you end up calling controller render twice.
The best option would be to create a dedicated template for your action and compose everything inside of it.
There is also render_to_string if you really need to render multiple things in a controller:
render json: {
  status: "OK",
  html: render_to_string(partial: "shared/my_partial"),
  other_important_stuff: foo
}


Thanks, that's very clear. I didn't know about render_to_string!

The devil is in the details here as you need to escape any entities in the HTML that are not valid for a JSON string like ".

@max render json: does some kind of escaping, i was assuming that's enough, no? {"status":"OK","html":"\u003cdiv id=\"id\"\u003e\"\u003c/div\u003e\n"}

@Alex - yes it does some escaping. The problem really is when dealing with quotes in text nodes and user provided content.

@max This is a very good point, thanks. The headaches of metaprogramming. Do you have an example of how this could go wrong? Say someone submits a comment with a quote in it, would this not be escaped in the same way above?

OWASP has some pretty good examples of XSS payloads.
